# How Do I Use NotifyServiceStatusChange to Get Notified When a Service Is Deleted?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

How can I use NotifyServiceStatusChange properly so I can get notified when the service specified is deleted? My current code successfully stops the service and marks it for deletion. However, I want to be notified when the service is fully deleted.

Here are the main points of my code:

```c
SC_HANDLE SCManager = OpenSCManagerW(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, 
     SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);

HANDLE EventHandle = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

SERVICE_NOTIFY ServiceNotify;
ServiceNotify.dwVersion = SERVICE_NOTIFY_STATUS_CHANGE;
ServiceNotify.pszServiceNames = ServiceName;
ServiceNotify.pContext = &EventHandle;
ServiceNotify.pfnNotifyCallback = (PFN_SC_NOTIFY_CALLBACK)CallbackFunction;
DWORD status = NotifyServiceStatusChangeW(SCManager, SERVICE_NOTIFY_DELETED, &ServiceNotify);

WaitForSingleObject(EventHandle, INFINITE);
CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
CloseHandle(EventHandle);
```

(ServiceName is `WCHAR*`)

CallbackFunction code:

```c
VOID CALLBACK CallbackFunction(IN PVOID pParameter) {
    SERVICE_NOTIFY* ServiceNotify = pParameter;
    HANDLE EventHandle = *(HANDLE*)ServiceNotify->pContext;
    SetEvent(EventHandle);
}
```

NotifyServiceStatusChange is returning ERROR_SUCCESS (0). However, my callback function is not being called at all. How can I fix this?

Edit:
Here is minimal reproducible code:

```c
void ErrorExit(char* FunctionName, unsigned long ErrorCode) {
    char* ErrorMessage;
    FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, ErrorCode, LANG_USER_DEFAULT, (LPTSTR)&ErrorMessage, 0, NULL);

    int MessageSize = (strlen(ErrorMessage) + strlen(FunctionName) + 50) * sizeof(char);
    char* FullMessage = malloc(MessageSize);
    sprintf_s(FullMessage, MessageSize, "%s failed with error %d: %s", FunctionName, ErrorCode, ErrorMessage);

    MessageBoxA(NULL, FullMessage, "Error", MB_OK);
    ExitProcess(ErrorCode);
}

PFN_SC_NOTIFY_CALLBACK CallbackFunction(PVOID pParameter) {
    printf("CallbackFunction has been called.\r\n");
    SERVICE_NOTIFY* ServiceNotify = pParameter;
    HANDLE EventHandle = ServiceNotify->pContext;
    if (!SetEvent(EventHandle)) {
        ErrorExit("SetEvent", GetLastError());
    }
}

int main()
{
    WCHAR* ServiceName = L"SERVICE NAME"; // Input service name here

    SC_HANDLE SCManager = OpenSCManagerW(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (!SCManager) { 
        ErrorExit("OpenSCManagerW", GetLastError()); 
    }

    SC_HANDLE ServiceHandle = OpenServiceW(SCManager, ServiceName,
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS | SERVICE_STOP | DELETE);
    if (!ServiceHandle) {
        ErrorExit("ServiceHandle", GetLastError());
    }

    if (!DeleteService(ServiceHandle)) {
        ErrorExit("DeleteService", GetLastError());
    }

    if (!CloseServiceHandle(ServiceHandle)) {
        ErrorExit("CloseServiceHandle", GetLastError());
    }

    HANDLE EventHandle = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!EventHandle) { 
        ErrorExit("CreateEventW", GetLastError()); 
    }

    SERVICE_NOTIFY ServiceNotify;
    ServiceNotify.dwVersion = SERVICE_NOTIFY_STATUS_CHANGE;
    ServiceNotify.pszServiceNames = ServiceName;
    ServiceNotify.pContext = EventHandle;
    ServiceNotify.pfnNotifyCallback = CallbackFunction;

    DWORD status = NotifyServiceStatusChangeW(SCManager, SERVICE_NOTIFY_DELETED, &ServiceNotify);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) { 
        ErrorExit("NotifyServiceStatusChangeW", GetLastError()); 
    }

    status = WaitForSingleObjectEx(EventHandle, INFINITE, TRUE);
    if (status == WAIT_FAILED) {
        ErrorExit("WaitForSingleObjectEx", GetLastError());
    }
    printf("WaitForSingleObjectEx Result: %lu\r\n", status);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, no other service depends on the service being deleted, and the service being deleted is already stopped. My error handling function "ErrorExit" is never called. Nothing is printed on the screen. My program simply pauses, which I assume is from WaitForSingleObjectEx.

I know the service is being deleted because I have ProcessHacker open, and it is giving me notifications that the service is being deleted.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but just an FYI, you don't need to use the `&` operator when assigning `EventHandle` to `pContext`, since `HANDLE` is already a pointer type.

Comment: Your callback function is declared wrong. `PFN_SC_NOTIFY_CALLBACK CallbackFunction(PVOID pParameter)` should be `VOID CALLBACK CallbackFunction(PVOID pParameter)` instead. Then you can get rid of the typecast when assigning `CallbackFunction` to `ServiceNotify.pfnNotifyCallback`

Comment: Also, `WCHAR* ServiceName = L"SERVICE NAME";` will not compile in any standard conforming compiler. You need to use `const WCHAR*` (aka `LPCWSTR`) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. Those suggestions helped make it work. I think the main thing was the fact that it was not ```const WCHAR*```. Can you either create a new answer or edit your original one so I can accept it?

Comment: No need for me to update anything, the example in my answer already conforms to all of the points I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NotifyServiceStatusChange is returning ERROR_SUCCESS (0). However, my callback function is not being called at all.

The [`NotifyServiceStatusChangeW` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-notifyservicestatuschangew) says:

> When the service status changes, the system invokes the specified callback function as an asynchronous procedure call (APC) queued to the calling thread. The calling thread must enter an alertable wait (for example, by calling the `SleepEx` function) to receive notification. For more information, see [Asynchronous Procedure Calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/asynchronous-procedure-calls).

So, make sure you are actually processing APC notifications while you wait. `WaitForSingleObject()` will not do that for you.

Use [`WaitForSingleObjectEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobjectex) instead.  It has a `bAlertable` parameter you can set to `TRUE`.  You will have to call it in a loop, since it will return when *any* APC call is processed by the calling thread, which may not be the one you are expecting.

You also need to call `NotifyServiceStatusChangeW()` in a loop, too.  The documentation does not mention this, but the callback will be called only 1 time per use. Once the callback is called, you need to call `NotifyServiceStatusChangeW()` again to receive another notification if the current one is not the event you are expecting.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
struct MyCallbackInfo {
    HANDLE EventHandle;
    LPCWSTR pszServiceName;
    bool bDeleted;
};

...

VOID CALLBACK CallbackFunction(PVOID pParameter) {
    SERVICE_NOTIFYW* ServiceNotify = (SERVICE_NOTIFYW*) pParameter;
    MyCallbackInfo *ci = (MyCallbackInfo*) ServiceNotify->pContext;

    if (ServiceNotify->dwNotificationStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        LPWSTR pServiceName = ServiceNotify->pszServiceNames;
        while (*pServiceName != L'\0') {
            if (lstrcmpW(pServiceName, ci->pszServiceName) == 0) {
                ci.bDeleted = true;
                break;
            }
            pServiceName += (lstrlenW(pServiceName) + 1);
        }
        LocalFree(ServiceNotify->pszServiceNames);
    }

    SetEvent(ci->EventHandle);
}

...

MyCallbackInfo ci;
ci.EventHandle = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
ci.pszServiceName = ServiceName;
ci.bDeleted = false;

if (!ci.EventHandle) {
    // error handling...
}

SC_HANDLE SCManager = OpenSCManagerW(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, 
     SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
if (!SCManager) {
    // error handling...
}

SERVICE_NOTIFYW ServiceNotify = {};
ServiceNotify.dwVersion = SERVICE_NOTIFY_STATUS_CHANGE;
ServiceNotify.pContext = &ci;
ServiceNotify.pfnNotifyCallback = CallbackFunction;

DWORD status;
do {
    status = NotifyServiceStatusChangeW(SCManager, SERVICE_NOTIFY_DELETED, &ServiceNotify);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // error handling...
    }

    while ((status = WaitForSingleObjectEx(ci.EventHandle, INFINITE, TRUE)) == WAIT_IO_COMPLETION);

    if (status == WAIT_FAILED) {
        // error handling...
    }

    if (ci.bDeleted) {
        // service has been deleted ...
        break;
    }

    ResetEvent(ci.EventHandle);
}
while (true);

CloseServiceHandle(SCManager);
CloseHandle(ci.EventHandle);
```

Comment: This answer probably helped prevent a future problem from occurring. However, my callback function is still not being called.

Comment: My callback function is still not being called. The remarks for SERVICE_NOTIFY say that the callback function is defined as ```typedef VOID( CALLBACK * PFN_SC_NOTIFY_CALLBACK ) ( IN PVOID pParameter );```. However, I am unaware of how to apply this.

Comment: @Hantalyte The callback in my answer satisfies that signature. If the callback is not being called, then either the service is not actually being deleted (are there open handles to it? Check with [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)), or you are doing something else wrong that we can't see. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73339204/edit) your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added minimal reproducible code.

Comment: @Hantalyte You are calling `DeleteService()` and `CloseServiceHandle()` before calling `NotifyServiceStatusChangeW()`, so it is entirely possible that the service is being fully deleted before you register for the `SERVICE_NOTIFY_DELETED` notification, thus there is no event to send to you.  Do the registration first.

Comment: If the service was already deleted, NotifyServiceStatusChange would fail with some error code saying how the specified service does not exist. I will adapt my code for the case that that does happen. However, that was not causing the issue.

Comment: @Hantalyte What you describe is true only when the 1st parameter of `NotifyServiceStatusChangeW()` is a handle to a specific service, but you are giving it a handle to the SCM instead. The SCM doesn't know which service(s) you are interested in (`SERVICE_NOTIFY::pszServiceNames` is NOT an input filter!). You are asking the SCM to notify you when *any* service is deleted. The callback will tell you *which* service(s) were deleted. That is why you need to move `NotifyServiceStatusChangeAW()` into a loop, in case other services get deleted before the one you are interested in.